# HazelCast crashes after caching lots of data with IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, caching, hazelcast

I have a Java web application with Spring and I am using Hazelcast 3.6 to cache lots of data I am retrieving from my Database Server.

With x amount of data my server and web application is running fine. But when I connect to a database with times the amount of data I was using, my web application seems to crash after some time with the following behavior:

1. Firstly the server loads up. HazelCast server loads up just fine and I am able to write some data into Hazelcast cache.
2. After some time running and caching I get the following exception when it tries to write some more data

> Target[Address[x.x.x.x]:5854] disconnected

3. And then every time it tries to Hazelcast cache data I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in
>   the config! The following addresses were tried:[/x.x.x.x:5854]

What do you think is happening?

[UPDATE] 
Here are the logs:

```
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6a3327b9, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@44751927, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60198 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6a3327b9, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@44751927, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@29fa4fd9, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@70904516, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60163 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@29fa4fd9, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@70904516, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60163 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@fa7e116, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@56aa7361, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60338 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@4a08fea, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@49484e05, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60336 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@fa7e116, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@56aa7361, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60338 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@fa7e116, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@56aa7361, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@124404e1, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@2f9c5925, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60213 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@124404e1, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@2f9c5925, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@1930fb2f, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@5ebad794, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60241 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6f3f10f5, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@15727de2, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60337 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6f3f10f5, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@15727de2, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60337 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6f3f10f5, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@15727de2, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@4a08fea, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@49484e05, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60336 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@4a08fea, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@49484e05, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@1930fb2f, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@5ebad794, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60241 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@1930fb2f, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@5ebad794, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@507d11ba, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@4316f39e, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60207 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@41a0a48e, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@1993884b, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60218 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@41a0a48e, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@1993884b, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60218 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@41a0a48e, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@1993884b, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@62c6250d, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@3eaaab24, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60208 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@62c6250d, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@3eaaab24, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@507d11ba, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@4316f39e, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60207 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@507d11ba, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@4316f39e, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@24d9010b, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@22d38c13, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60242 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@24d9010b, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@22d38c13, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6e914541, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@359e71d, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60206 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@36c9e8a0, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@1c77c7a, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:60219 remote=/127.0.0.1:5802]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@36c9e8a0, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@1c77c7a, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@6e914541, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@359e71d, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@29fa4fd9, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@70904516, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@63c6728d, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@798aba27, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@49617323, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@1cce2478, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:14 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [/127.0.0.1:5802] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:16 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@63c6728d, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@798aba27, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:16 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture
WARNING: The Future.set() method can only be called once. Request: ClientMessage{length=39, correlationId=801271, messageType=126, partitionId=-1, isComplete=true, isRetryable=false, isEvent=false, writeOffset=0}, current response: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException, new response: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Target[Address[135.128.250.146]:5802] disconnected.
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:16 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture
WARNING: The Future.set() method can only be called once. Request: ClientMessage{length=52, correlationId=801275, messageType=12d, partitionId=-1, isComplete=true, isRetryable=false, isEvent=false, writeOffset=0}, current response: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException, new response: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Target[Address[135.128.250.146]:5802] disconnected.
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:16 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl
WARNING: Heartbeat is back to healthy for connection : ClientConnection{live=false, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@17d42c7b, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@6ab44b75, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[135.128.250.146]:5802}
Sep 26, 2017 12:36:16 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientPartitionService
WARNING: Error while fetching cluster partition table!
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Target[Address[135.128.250.146]:5802] disconnected.
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:146)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.access$000(ClientInvocationFuture.java:38)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture$1.run(ClientInvocationFuture.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Target[Address[135.128.250.146]:5802] disconnected.
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$CleanResourcesTask$1.createNew(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:230)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$CleanResourcesTask$1.createNew(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport.cleanResources(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.cleanResources(ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$CleanResourcesTask.run(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:133)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Well, what do the logs of your Hazelcast server say?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the logs

Answer (score 0):

Target disconnected means Hazelcast server is not connected. Hazelcast logs should give you  details of what happened in your cluster.

Comment: This log snippet only shows what happened after the disconnect but you need to figure out the reason of the disconnect, which would appear before this disconnect event in the log. I'd say do check out your gc logs too.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. I have added some more logs but there is nothing helpful on the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to relate this to server logs and figure out what the servers were doing at the time of this connection failure. Some of the common causes for server disconnections are network failures and GC problems. A gc pause, if long enough to breach configured threshold, will result in that server node getting kicked out of the cluster.